# If $f$ is a convex increasing real function with $x \geq y$, $x,y\geq 0$, prove that $f(x)-f(y) \geq f(x-y)$.

Tags: analysis

Having the assumption that f is a convex increasing function,with $x \geq y$ , $x,y\geq 0$. How can I prove that $f(x)-f(y) \geq f(x-y)$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: $f(x)= x$ is convex and increasing.

Comment: What have you tried? At least write down the definition of "convex" in your question.

Comment: It can't possibly hold in general. Even if you find such an $f$, $x$, and $y$ such that $f(x) - f(y) \ge f(x - y)$, then $g(x) = f(x) + C$ will also be convex and increasing for any $C$. As we increase $C$, $g(x) - g(y)$ will remain the same as $f(x) - f(y)$, but $g(x - y) = f(x - y) + C$, i.e. it will increase without bound.

Comment: I think this is true if and only if $f(0)\leq 0.$

Comment: @AdamRubinson that's pretty what my intuition arrived to. Do you have an idea on how to formalize it? I tried by contradiction but it did not work out

Comment: " that's pretty what my intuition arrived to." But that's not what your question was. Either add this condition to your question or accept one of the currently correct answers and ask this as a new question. I'm not going to answer the question, "How can I prove that if $f$ is a convex increasing function with $f(0)\leq 0,\ $ and $\ x \geq y,\ x,y\geq 0$ then $\ f(x)-f(y) \geq f(x-y)$ ?" because this is not the question at the top of the page. It should be clear now that changing the goalpost of the question after you've asked it causes problems, so please refrain from doing this in future.

Comment: It's always a shame when a potentially interesting question is ruined by bad question writing due to zero effort.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is not true. Just take $f(x)=e^x$. This is a monotonically increasing and convex function. But for $x=0$ and $y=1000$ we have
$$
f(x-y)=f(-1000)>0>1-e^{1000}=f(x)-f(y).
$$

Comment: I edited the question with further details. Does it hold in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x)=e^x+1000$, which is a monotonically increasing and convex function. Take $x=2$  and $y=1$, then

$$f(2-1)=e+1000 > e^2-e^1=(e^2+1000)-(e^1+1000)=f(2)-f(1).$$